# CSS media query not working on iphone 5

Tags: css, media-queries

I am making use of css media queries to build a responsive site. 
Here is a page in question: http://sergedenimes.com/shop/.

I have used this query to activate style for smartpones:

```
    @media only screen 
and (max-width:640px){
    //styles
}
```

When I resize my browser the styles are picked up and I get the smartphone layout. However when I visit the page on my iphone 5 the media query seems to not be picked up. Any ideas why? I have another site that uses the same media query and it works fine.

Tested in Chrome and Firefox on mac, and Chrome and Safari on iphone.

Comment: It gets picked up? As in activated? That's correct behavior.

Comment: Sorry, typo. It does **not** get picked up by the smartphone

Comment: Maybe because max-width means the maximum width (a less than)

Comment: Yes, as in all viewport widths less than or equal to 640px, which I believe the iphone 5 falls into.

Comment: Try adding this to your document `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson if you must downvote/vote to close it would be helpful to know the reason. Others understood my question, which was genuine, and helpfully produced the answer.

Comment: I didn't say you did, but someone did and I presume you downvoted. But it is a presumption so I apologise if I am wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have no `<meta name="viewport">` tag, so the iPhone is applying a scale to your page to fit the screen.

**Edit**

Kris Hollenbeck beat me to it. Try adding this tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: That is indeed the reason. Many thanks. Kris may have beaten you but you posted the answer ;)